# Extend expiration for temporary credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get temporary credentials from **getCredentialsForIdentity** cognito identity pool api. But I am not getting how to extend the credentials expiration. I came across  **assumeRoleWithSaml** sts api but using that I can't link the saml authentication with federated identity pool. Is there any work around by which I can extend the credential expiration time and link that to federated identity pool.
I have provided Role which has maxDuration set to 12 hours.